# Use Window.URL in mozilla - JavaStript

Tags: javascript, mozilla

I want to use Window.URL object in my JavaScript code.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/URL

```
stream => video.src = URL.createObjectUrl(stream);
```

I was trying also with object Window.URL, wundow.webkitURL, but in console I'm getting

> URL.createObjectUrl is not a function

or object not found.

Should I make some import or something to use Window object in my code?

I'm using mozilla v46.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> URL.createObjectUrl is not a function

`URL` at `createObjectUrl` should be in uppercase characters

```
URL.createObjectURL(stream);
```